# MVC4 Web API - OK to delete all views/javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Just created a new MVC4 Web API project - however I don't want any client-side for this, just the back-end to be referenced from other clients.

Is there any, sensible, reason that the default project template includes all of the javascript, views, etc?

Can they be removed without issue?

Comment: Yes, you can remove them, and HomeController.cs too.

Comment: I'm guessing that also goes for all the script bundles, css etc?

Comment: Yes, they can go too.

Answer (score 0):

Default the web api project also contains the regular mvc stuff. If you do not intent to use the web api help pages (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage) or intend to develop a website part next to your api you can easily remove all views, scripts & statics.

Comment: New to this...does this generate the equivalent of a wsdl?

Comment: No, alas, it generates html pages with example usage + responses. It can use your documentation to do this (see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages => 'Adding API Documentation'). There are other solutions to generate swagger documentation (http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/).